# Passing file location of a Dynamic Generated link

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

Using ASP.net and c#
using visual studio 2010

Hi all, I hope some one can help me. Basically I have a page that has a grid view that has a link button in one of the columns. What I'm trying to do is; user clicks the link and the PDF file it refers to is loaded in a new page using the site.master.  Below is the code I currently have.

Starting page

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Guides] WHERE (([Display] = ?) AND ([Media_Document] = ?))">

<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="true" Name="Display" 
    QueryStringField="checkbox" Type="Boolean" />
    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="Document" Name="Media_Document" 
    QueryStringField="Media_Document" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>

</asp:AccessDataSource>
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
DataKeyNames="ID"  CssClass="mGrid"  RowStyle-CssClass="pgr"  AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" Width="225px" style="text-align:left" 
GridLines="None" >

<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>

<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Guide" HeaderText="Guide" SortExpression="Guide" />
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="File_location" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="Guides.aspx?File_location={0}" 
    Target="content" Text="Link" />
</Columns>

<RowStyle CssClass="pgr"></RowStyle>

</asp:GridView> 
</div>
```

This code generates the link correctly which is  `Guides.aspx?File_location=blahblahblah.pdf`

**Destination page**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <object width="800" height="800" data="File_Location"></object>
</asp:Content>
```

This dose not work because the variable `File_location` is not recognized which makes sense. I could get the location using c# in the code behind but how do I then display that in the page?

Any Ideas?

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class Guides : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Location = Request.QueryString.ToString();

        File_location(Location);

    }


    public void File_location(string location)
    {

        string File_Location = location.Substring(location.IndexOf('=') + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to have a public property on the code behind page called File_Location and then you would refer to it like this:

```
<object width="800" height="800" data="<%=File_Location%>"></object>
```

Set the value in Page_load.

create a property in the code-behind like this:

```
public string File_location()
{
    get
    {
        string location = Request.QueryString;
        return = location.Substring(location.IndexOf('=') + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you quick reply. I was really excited about this because It looked like exactly what I was after. So I wrote a bit of code behind to get the query string the was being passed. But i still get The name 'File_Location' does not exist in the current context. I have added my code behind to the original question. many thanks

Comment: Im pretty sure your answer is what I was looking for, but no it's still a problem. I put the result of the code behind in a label just to test and it displays the correct location ie: documents/blahblahblah.pdf. But it says 'File_Location' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: In your above code, File_location is not a public property.  It's a method.

Comment: Try using this

    public string File_location()
    {
        get
        {
            string location = Request.QueryString;
            return = location.Substring(location.IndexOf('=') + 1);
        }
    }